# Is IEEE-754 representation used in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I have to encode the electron charge, which is -1.602*10<sup>-19</sup> C, using IEEE-754. I did it manually and verified my result using [this](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) site. So I know my representation is good. My problem is that, if I try to build a C program showing my number in scientific notation, I get the wrong number.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float q = 0xa03d217b;
    printf("q = %e", q);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
$ ./test.exe
q = 2.688361e+09
```

My question: Is there another representation that my CPU might be using internally for floating point other than IEEE-754?

Comment: If you want precision why are you using `float` instead of `double`? What is the motivation behind using a hexadecimal encoded float? This is all a very, very bad idea.

Comment: `double q = -1.602e-19`. Done. Don't play games here, you'll win dumb prizes. Just express it in its minimal form.

Comment: What CPU are you using? Did you read the documentation for it to check how a `float` is represented internally? Did you account for [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues?

Comment: I precisely have to encode the number on 32 bits. I also forgot to mention that this is an exercise. I had to encode the number using IEEE754 manually. This C program is just here to verify the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line `float q = 0xa03d217b;` converts the *integer (hex) literal* into a `float` value representing that number (or an approximation thereof); thus, the value assigned to your `q` will be the (decimal) value `2,688,360,827` (which is what `0xa03d217b` equates to), as you have noted.

If you *must* initialize a `float` variable with its internal IEEE-754 (HEX) representation, then your best option is to use [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) *via* the members of a `union` (legal in C but *not* in C++):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    float f;
    unsigned int h;
} hexfloat;

int main()
{
    hexfloat hf;
    hf.h = 0xa03d217b;
    float q = hf.f;
    printf("%lg\n", q);
    return 0;
}
```

---

There are also some 'quick tricks' using pointer casting, like:

```c
unsigned iee = 0xa03d217b;
float q = *(float*)(&iee);
```

But, be aware, there are numerous issues with such approaches, like [potential endianness conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and the fact that you're breaking [strict aliasing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/10871073).

Comment: This is probably the original intent, but yeah, there's a *lot* of caveats, so it's nice of you to lay those out.

Comment: You can avoid the aliasing problems by using a `union`, and I've never seen nor heard of a machine that uses different endianness for ints and floats, but it is technically possible.  More likely is a machine that uses non-IEEE fp, though those are rare these days.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I was adding my edit while you were posting your comment.

Comment: Why bother giving somebody an improper method when an easy proper method exists? There is no reason to present the aliasing-via-pointer method at all. The union method is fine in C, but so is copying bytes, and that is defined (up to implementation issues) in C and C++.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point. I have rearranged my answer to put the 'proper' method first; however, I have retained the 'improper' method by way of a warning *not* to use it. I have not included the method using `memcpy` (although it is good) because that is **your** answer, not mine.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that if I try to build a c program showing my the number in scientific notation.

What if your target machine might or might not use  IEEE754 encoding?  Copying the bit pattern may fail.

If starting with a [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) constant 0xa03d217b, code could examine it and then build up the best `float` available for that implementation.

```
#include <math.h>
#define BINARY32_MASK_SIGN 0x80000000
#define BINARY32_MASK_EXPO 0x7FE00000
#define BINARY32_MASK_SNCD 0x007FFFFF
#define BINARY32_IMPLIED_BIT 0x800000
#define BINARY32_SHIFT_EXPO 23

float binary32_to_float(uint32_t x) {
  // Break up into 3 parts
  bool sign = x & BINARY32_MASK_SIGN;
  int biased_expo = (x & BINARY32_MASK_EXPO) >> BINARY32_SHIFT_EXPO;
  int32_t significand = x & BINARY32_MASK_SNCD;

  float y;
  if (biased_expo == 0xFF) {
    y = significand ? NAN : INFINITY;  // For simplicity, NaN payload not copied
  } else {
    int expo;
    if (biased_expo > 0) {
      significand |= BINARY32_IMPLIED_BIT;
      expo = biased_expo - 127;
    } else {
      expo = 126;
    }
    y = ldexpf((float)significand, expo - BINARY32_SHIFT_EXPO);
  }
  if (sign) {
    y = -y;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Sample usage and output

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  float e = -1.602e-19;
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, e);
  uint32_t e_as_binary32 = 0xa03d217b;
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, binary32_to_float(e_as_binary32));
}

-1.602000046e-19
-1.602000046e-19
```

Answer (score 1):

Hence, `q` doesn't not contains the value you expect. The hex value is converted to a float with the same value (with approximation), not with the same bit-representation.

When compiled with g++ and the option -Wall, there is a warning:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'float' changes value from 2688360827 to 2688360704 [-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion]
```

Can be tested [on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/W118z9).

This warning is apparently not supported by gcc. Instead, you can use the option -Wfloat-conversion (with is not part of -Wall -Wextra):

```
warning: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'float' changes value from '2688360827' to '2.6883607e+9f' [-Wfloat-conversion]
```

Again [on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/964En4).

Answer (score 0):

Note that C supports hexadecimal-floating point numbers as literals. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal for details. This notation is useful to write the number in a portable way, without any concern for rounding issues as would be the case if you write it in regular decimal/scientific notation. Here's the number you're interested in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   float f = -0x1.7a42f6p-63;

   printf("%e\n", f);
   return 0;
};
```

When I run this program, I get:

```
$ make a
cc     a.c   -o a
$ ./a
-1.602000e-19
```

So long as your compiler supports this notation, you need not worry about how the underlying machine represents floats, so long as this particular number fits into its `float` representation.